# I don't know what ADODB.Recordset is

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I am converting a VB6 app to C#. I am starting on the top of the VB6 app and going from there. What is all the RS. stuff? I don't understand?

```
Sub Main()
    Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim FileName As String, FilePath As String
    Dim Test As Boolean
    Dim ResultCode As xcdError

    Dim oAccess As Access.Application
    Dim Zip_File As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Make a connection to the database
    Call MakeDBConnection

    ' Create a recordset of the directories to check
    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

    RS.ActiveConnection = DB
    RS.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    RS.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    RS.Open "Select ConversionDefinition.* From ConversionDefinition"
    ' Check the directories for Raw Data
    ' If the required data is found, then start the coversion application
    If Not (RS.EOF And RS.BOF) Then
        RS.MoveFirst
        Do While Not (RS.EOF)
```

Comment: I hope it's a small application. If not, you might want to consider using a third-party converter like [Artinsoft's tool](http://www.artinsoft.com/vbc_csharpgen.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_recordset.asp)

The page explains it pretty well. It is an ADO DabaBase RecordSet.

Answer (score 1):

It was the forerunner of ADO.NET.  You can still use it in a C# program, it would make the conversion a lot less painful.  Project + Add Reference, COM tab, select "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library".  Earlier versions of Window might have 2.7.  The statements should convert about one-to-one.

The .NET equivalent are the classes in the System.Data.OleDb namespace if you still work with Access databases.  Using them will require a fairly heavy rewrite.

Comment: +1 Good idea to convert in steps, first making a working, tested C# program using ADODB and converting to use ADO.Net later.